# How is the substitution $y$ by $\varphi (x)$ rigorously valid from the theory of integration?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I'm reading a proof of below theorem, i.e.,

---

Let $X, Y$ be Polish spaces, $\mu \in \mathcal P(X), \nu \in \mathcal P(Y)$, and $\varphi:X \to Y$ measurable.

> **Theorem:** If $\pi \in \mathcal P(X \times Y)$ with marginals $\mu, \nu$ respectively is such that $y = \varphi (x)$ for $\pi$-a.e. $(x, y) \in X \times Y$, then $\nu = \varphi_\sharp \mu$.

**Proof:** Let $P^X, P^Y$ be the projections from $X \times Y$ to $X,Y$ respectively. Then $\mu = P^X_\sharp \pi$ and $\nu = P^Y_\sharp \pi$. For $f \in L_1 (\nu)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{Y} f(y) \mathrm d \nu (y) &= \int_{Y} f(y) \mathrm d (P^Y_\sharp \pi) (y) \\
&= \int_{X \times Y} f \circ P^Y (x, y) \mathrm d \pi (x, y) \\
&\overset{(\star)}{=} \int_{X \times Y} f \circ P^Y (x, \varphi (x)) \mathrm d \pi (x, y) \\
&= \int_{X \times Y} f \circ \varphi \circ P^X (x, y) \mathrm d \pi (x, y) \\
&= \int_{X} f \circ \varphi \mathrm d (P^X_\sharp \pi) (x) \\
&= \int_{X} f \circ \varphi \mathrm d \mu (x) \\
&= \int_{Y} f \mathrm d (\varphi_\sharp\mu) (y).
\end{align}
$$

Here $(\star)$ is due to $y = \varphi (x)$ for $\pi$-a.e. $(x, y) \in X \times Y$. It follows that $\nu = \varphi_\sharp\mu$.

---

The substitution of $y$ by $\varphi (x)$ is very intuitive in $(\star)$. However, I could not get how such substitution is rigorously/logically valid from the theory of integration. Could you elaborate on my confusion?

---

**Update:** With a similar reasoning, we get $(\operatorname{Id}, \varphi)_\sharp \mu = \pi$ with $\operatorname{Id}: X \to X$ the identity map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f \circ P^Y (x, y) \mathrm  
 {=} \ f \circ P^Y (x, \varphi (x)) $$
almost everywhere with respect to $\pi$, so the integral of the LHS with respect to $\pi$ equals the integral of the RHS with respect to $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you so much professor Peres! Your answer enlightens me.